# EXTJS update a managed iframe panel

Tags: extjs

At this link:
http://code.google.com/p/managediframe/
This is how they update a mangediframe with static content:
IFrameEl.update("New content");
This works for me fine.
But I have something like this:

```
function update(someText){
alert(someText);
someIframePanel.update(someText);
}
```

This does not work. With static text as in the internet example, the panel is updated, but not with dynamic text passed as function argument.
What am i missing?
Thank you.
EDIT: There is no error, but the panel does not get updated with `someText`.
I tried this:

```
someIframePanel.update('1');
```

It updates the panel with 1.
But this does not update the panel :

```
someIframePanel.update(1);
```

Comment: code snippet of what doesnt work (and maybe even one for what works)?

Comment: Are you getting an error? #define "Doesn'tWork"? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to do:
someIframePanel.update(Ext.util.JSON.encode(someText));